# NPOI Parallel.ForEachAsync Write to Same File

Tags: asp.net-core, npoi

So I have a `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop like so:

```cs
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(batchSysIds, parallelOptions, async (batchSysId, _) =>
{
    await GenerateListWriteFile(batchSysId);
});
```

So basically I'm generating a new list and then writing said list to excel file:

```cs
private static async Task GenerateListWriteFile( long batchSysId)
{
   var newList= await GenerateList(batchSysId);
   await WriteToFile(newList);
}
```

This is the code for writing to file:

```cs
public async Task WriteToExcel(List<ResultFile> results)
{
   DataTable table = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results), (typeof(DataTable)));
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

   try
   {
      using (var fs = new FileStream(File_Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
      {
          IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
          ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

          List<string> columns = new();
          IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
          int columnIndex = 0;

          foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
          {
             columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
             row.CreateCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(column.ColumnName);
             columnIndex++;
          }

          int rowIndex = 1;
          foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
          {
              row = excelSheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
              int cellIndex = 0;
              foreach (String col in columns)
              {                       
                row.CreateCell(cellIndex).SetCellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
                cellIndex++;
              }

              rowIndex++;
          }
          workbook.Write(fs, false);
          workbook.Close();
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        logger.Error(ex, $"Error writing to file");
     }
}
```

So when the program tries to write to the same **result.xlsx** file, it gives me the following error:

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\\result.xlsx' because it is being used by another process

Is it possible to write to the same file like this? Or do I need to create a separate file for each thread and then combine all of the files together? Or are there any better ways of writing to a single file without running into this issue?

EDIT:
Tried `lock` to see if it works or not, it didn't:

```cs
public async Task WriteToExcel(List<ResultFile> results)
        {
            DataTable table = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results), (typeof(DataTable)));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(File_Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

                    lock (workbook)
                    {
                        List<string> columns = new();
                        IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
                        int columnIndex = 0;

                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
                            row.CreateCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(column.ColumnName);
                            columnIndex++;
                        }

                        int rowIndex = 1;
                        foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                        {
                            row = excelSheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
                            int cellIndex = 0;
                            foreach (String col in columns)
                            {
                                row.CreateCell(cellIndex).SetCellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
                                cellIndex++;
                            }

                            rowIndex++;
                        }

                        workbook.Write(fs, false);
                        workbook.Close(); 
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, $"Error writing to file");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use a `lock` statement when writing to the file. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CharlesHan Lock statement? Sorry not familiar with that, how does it work?

Comment: Basically, you put a `lock` on the file, and only one thread writes the data at a time. I am unsure how much performance you will gain depending on how the list is generated. For the `lock` you can read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: @CharlesHan tried it. Seems the issue still persists

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the `lock` like this,

```
private readonly object fileLock = new object();

public async Task WriteToExcel(List<ResultFile> results)
{
   lock (fileLock)
   {
      DataTable table = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results), (typeof(DataTable)));
      var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

      try
      {
         //your existing code here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Even this doesn't seem to solve the issue

Comment: Can you show me the classes? Are the three methods in the same class or separate ones?